# Different result for positional parameters expansion and custom array expansion

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

There is a difference in the output of commands that I don't understand, as stated below:

```
INPUT="$@"
echo "$INPUT ${#INPUT} ${#INPUT[@]} ${#@}"
# outputs: a b c 5 1 3

arr=(a b c)
echo "$arr ${#arr} ${#arr[@]}"
# outputs: a 1 3
```

I run a script with `./my_script.sh a b c`.

I understand that `echo "$arr"`  is dereferencing `$arr` to the first element, and then printing `a`. At the same time for the command `$INPUT` it prints `a b c`.

For the command `${#INPUT}` and `${#INPUT[@]}` why is the output `5` and `1` respectively. Shouldn't it be similar to output of the commands `${#arr}` and `${#arr[@]}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assigned the array `$@` to a *scalar* `INPUT`, which resulted in the string `a b c`, to which the length computation says 5 and the number of elements in the "array" is 1.

Perhaps you meant to assign the array as an array?

```
input=( "$@" )
```

Comment: ok, So the shell aggregates the positional parameters and two spaces to output 5.

Comment: Does "$#" expand to a number or a string?

Comment: What's the practical difference? It's a "string" of bytes that corresponds to a number. You can use it in numerical comparisons.

Comment: I am trying to execute a programme with command `./my_script 1992`. In the logic I do a `if` conditional `if [[ "$#" -eq 0 || "$#" -gt 1 ]] then` ` echo "Usage: error` `else ...`. I always get only the error message, whereas `echo "$#"` outputs `1`.

Comment: the `||` operators aren't valid *inside* `[[` -- move them outside, or simplify the test: `if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]...`

Comment: On the page [https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals], it says, `||` is an additional test supported only by `[[`.  _EXPR || EXPR: Much like the '-o' operator of test, but does not evaluate the second expression if the first already turns out to be true._

Comment: `if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]...` doesn't work either. Only the error is output.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth a new question? Be sure to show the sh-bang line of the script and how you're invoking it.