# Numeric operators: if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]] always outputs true, whereas -- echo "$#" -- outputs 1

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to output `success` when number of positional parameters is equal to 1, error otherwise.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo() {
  if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]
  then echo "error"
  else
    echo "success"
  fi
}
foo
```

I execute the script with command `./my_script 1`. The output is always `error` no matter if I run the script with command `./my_script 1` or `./my_script 1 2`.

I expect `./my_script 1` to output *success*.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results, are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere?  If you add `echo "$#"` to a line before your test construct, can you confirm it's recognizing the correct number of arguments?

Comment: I think I do have a typo

Comment: I reproduced the exact situation. Yes, `echo "$#"` is recognising the correct number of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for [posting a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486618/different-result-for-positional-parameters-expansion-and-custom-array-expansion#comment892524_486620)! Seeing the code in use clarifies the situation.

You've passed along one argument to the overall script, but *no* arguments to the `foo` function!

If you want the *script's* arguments inside the function, pass them along:

```
foo() {
  if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]
  then echo "error"
  else
    echo "success"
  fi
}
foo "$@"
```

Comment: The operators `||` are valid inside `[[`.

Comment: Fair enough; I've never used them that way.